# Images not anchoring correctly?

Tags: html, image, anchor

Okay im creating a mobile site and I have a page of images and when someone clicks on a image I want it to go to that same image on a different page so im marking the images with `<a name="picname">` and then linking them like this:

```
<a href="pagename.html#picname"><img src="filepath/picname.jpg" border="1"></a>
```

But when I click on a image in a mobile browser it will skip to like right under the image (so you cant see it till you scroll up) what am I doing wrong?

> Snippet on page_1.html

```
<a href="gallery.html#1"><img src="gallery/1.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
<br><br>
<a href="gallery.html#2"><img src="gallery/2.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
<br><br>
<a href="gallery.html#3"><img src="gallery/3.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
<br><br>
<a href="gallery.html#4"><img src="gallery/4.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
<br><br>
<a href="gallery.html#5"><img src="gallery/5.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
<br><br>
<a href="gallery.html#6"><img src="gallery/6.jpg" width="95%" border="1"></a>
```

> Snippet on gallery.html

```
<a name="1"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/1.jpg"><br>
<a name="2"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/2.jpg"><br>
<a name="3"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/3.jpg"><br>
<a name="4"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/4.jpg"><br>
<a name="5"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/5.jpg"><br>
<a name="6"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/6.jpg"><br>
```

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Could you post a snippet of HTML source from the destination page?

Comment: @extols I added the snippets.

Comment: I found a solution, if you use `<img width="95%" border="2" src="gallery/1.jpg"><a name="1"></a>` instead of `<a name="1"></a><img width="95%" border="2" src="gallery/1.jpg">` it works fine! I have no idea why, but it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try put the anchor close tag before the image?

```
<a href="#" name="picname"><!-- --></a>
<img src="file.jpg" />
```

Comment: `<a name="1"></a><img width="95%" border="2" alt="" src="gallery/1.jpg">` Yeah, but it still goes below the image.

Comment: I put the tag after the image and it worked fine, thanks for your answser thou!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you create an individual anchor tag preceding the content you wish to "scroll" to and create a link in another location (either above/below in the same page or on another page).

It sounds like you want a new window to pop up and scroll down to the image? If that's the case, you're going to want to do something like this:

(For this example, we'll pretend that the page name is 'gallery.html')

```
<a href="gallery.html#picid" target="_blank">Click here for this image</a>
```

And lower on the page (or where ever it may be):

```
<a name="picid"></a>
<img src="image.png" border="0" />
```

This will work. I have tested it. If you don't actually want it to open in a new window, just remove the 'target="_blank" ' from the initial hyperlink anchor tag. The problem is that once you add an href, it becomes a hyperlink instead of a standard anchor.

If you wish to have the image clickable and have the page open in a new window (and automatically scroll to the image's location) when you click on the image, the proper setup would be:

```
<a name="picid"></a>
<a href="gallery.html#picid" target="_blank"><img src="image.png" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: I tried adding the `target="_blank"` in the `<a href="gallery.html#pic">` and it still went below the pic when I clicked on it.

Comment: If you give the link a target, it's going to open in a new window. It's important that the

    <a name="picid"></a> 

is above the image being linked.

Comment: It also appears that the reason why it was going "below" the image is because your achor tag is on the same line as the image (in your snippets). The anchor links go down TO the anchor tag, which pulls it out of the screen (so that it displays the content below it).

Comment: I think your right, because I put the anchor tag after the images and it worked fine! :)